# Are how to use search engines to find Unix/Linux-related information appropriate for this website?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question I was just writing up, but when I realized Unix & Linux SE does not have a `search-engine` tag I thought that maybe this question would be considered off-topic for this site. Here is the question:

> I would like to know if there is anyway I can search for Zsh themes
>   that fulfil several specific criteria I specify to the search.
>   Presently all search engines for Zsh themes I have found (including
>   [zshthem.es](http://zshthem.es/)) do not appear to allow me to search
>   for multiple specific features the theme possesses.
>
> ### An Example to Clarify what I mean
>
> For example, at the moment I am interested in using a Zsh theme with all of the following features:
>
> - They display the local time in AM/PM format
> - If the current working directory is a git repository it indicates whether or not all local changes have been pushed upstream.
> - It uses different symbols for root and user prompts, respectively.
> - It displays the hostname, username (e.g., `root` in a root prompt and the username in a non-root prompt) and a shortened form of the
>     present working directory.
>
> An example of what I am referring to with each of these criteria, is
>   that previously I was using the `gentoo` Zsh theme, which for me
>   (username: fusion809) when my current working directory is a git
>   repository at `~/GitHub/PKGBUILDs/enlightenment` which has unstaged
>   commits displays: `fusion809@brenton-pc
>   ~/GitHub/PKGBUILDs/enlightenment (master*) $` as my user prompt. Where
>   `brenton-pc` is my username, `~/GitHub/PKGBUILDs/enlightenment` is the
>   "shortened form of the present working directory" I was referring to,
>   with the long form being, of course,
>   `/home/fusion809/GitHub/PKGBUILDs/enlightenment`. The `master*` is how
>   this theme indicates that I have unstaged commits to the git
>   repository I am presently in. The dollar sign (`$`) denotes that the
>   prompt is a user prompt, not a root prompt. So, the only thing the
>   Gentoo theme lacks that I would like at the moment is that it does not
>   display the local time in AM/PM format.
>
> ### Summary
>
> I want to be clear that my question is not me asking what theme fulfils the  criteria I outlined in the previous "An Example to
>   Clarify what I mean" section, but rather how I can search for such
>   themes myself using a search engine or (if it is possible, which I
>   suspect not) from the command-line.

so essentially I want to know if this question is on-topic and whether other questions relating to searching for themes, plugins, *etc.* for Unix/Linux software would be considered on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't consider this on topic here because it essentially depends on someone, somewhere, building a site that is for sharing Zsh prompts and includes facility for tagging said prompts with the various features you describe.

It sounds more like a unicorn hunt than a procedure that will be of benefit to other Unix & Linux readers. Especially because you could just as easily write the prompt that you want yourself, using [Zsh's excellent documentation](http://zshwiki.org/home/config/prompt) and the many examples that are available on places like github.